# Phoenix Operating System - kernel system call for longest descendant with no children

Tags: operating-system

Can you please help me develop a syscall for kernel to return the pid of the process that has the longest descendants path leading to a process that has no children?
I am supposed to return the length of this path. Skip the process with the pid identifier specified in the parameter.

I managed to install phoenix in my ubuntu system. I was able to do the maxChildren syscall, but I have no idea how to implement the longestDescendant syscall.

For now I only have:
int syscall_longestDescendants(void * unstack) { }